# drupal 8, how debug a class?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I want to train myself to use Drupal 8 (Im from drupal 7 =) ). So, I learned some symfony2 basics. 
Now, I would like know if there is a good way about the code debugging, I mean :
Before with Drupal 7, I used the devel module for show the content of data (very usefull !). I try this module for drupal 8 but the dpm function seems not work in the class context.

Bu example, I use this code for alter some route :

```
<?php
namespace...
use...
...

class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase{
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection){
    // What is the best way for display the $collection array ? like a dpm ? 
    dpm($collection); // doen't work, nothing appears in any page
  }
```

Thanks =)

Comment: Take a look here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106166/drupal-8-devel-dpm-does-not-expand-drupal-node-entity-node

Answer (score 1):

Use `debug()` in Drupal 8. `debug()` will print the content of the variables as messages on the site. Alternatively, you can use a debugging tool like xdebug to examine your variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to using the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) debug functions like `dsm()` and `dpm()`, you would feel right at home using [Devel Kint](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/fat763/2155159).
Just enable the module Devel Kint and use it in modules or theme with `kint($variables)`.

I would also look into using [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) and setting break points to debug at a deeper level.